# Equivalent to Xamarin Frame in WPF

Tags: wpf, xamarin, wpf-controls, frame

I created a Xamarin solution and want to replace the UWP content by WPF.
In Xamarin I am using the `Frame` class. Is there any equivalent to a Xamarin `Frame` in WPF?
I can not find a documentation where this is described.

I am happy about any hint.

Comment: An equivalent would be eigther a Window (an actual window with border and closing buttons) or a a <Frame/> which could contain pages

Comment: I need it to define border and other properties for a control that will be put inside. So Window is not what I need. Frame also seems to be the wrong way but thx for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Xamarin.Forms [Frame](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.frame?view=xamarin-forms) is an element that contains a single child, with some framing options. You could basically achieve the same thing with a Border element in WPF:

```
<Border Padding="20" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="1" Background="Black"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock Text="I've been framed!" />
</Border>
```

Comment: Thx @mm8, but that only fits my border and not the other framing options. Is there no equivalent?

Comment: What other framing options? As mentioned by @Denis Schaf, there is a [Frame](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.frame?view=netframework-4.7.2) control that supports navigation. You could set the `Content` of the `Frame` to a `Page` that contains a `Border` or any other element.

Comment: What about coordinates and scale that can be set on frame?

Comment: In WPF, you would use a [ScaleTransform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-scale-an-element) to scale an element.

Comment: Thx, that's what I was looking for